# AFNetworking + NSOperation issues with concurrent requests

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, afnetworking

i got some problems when using AFNetworking in my project.
let's see:

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

AFJSONRequestOperation* op1 = [self operationSyncLeagues]; //URL=http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?lastsynced=1340362261&task=league.listall_syncable&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85

AFJSONRequestOperation* op2 =[self operationSyncMatches]; // URL = http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?pagesize=10&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85&page=1&league_id=51&lastsynced=1340362314&task=match.schedule_syncable

[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:4];
[queue addOperations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: op1, op2, nil] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

and now, let's take a look with my Logs (i put some NSLog in AFURLConnectionOperation.m for debugging):

> 2 operations start at the same time. fine!

2012-06-26 00:28:21.688 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[START] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?lastsynced=1340362261&task=league.listall_syncable&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85

2012-06-26 00:28:21.689 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[START] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?pagesize=10&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85&page=1&league_id=51&lastsynced=1340362314&task=match.schedule_syncable

> no redirection but why it fire willSendRequest? could check my API's url for detail

2012-06-26 00:28:21.689 zozo[11726:18d03] willSendRequest [redirectResponse description]:(null)
2012-06-26 00:28:21.690 zozo[11726:18d03] willSendRequest [redirectResponse description]:(null)

2012-06-26 00:28:21.913 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[90 bytes] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?lastsynced=1340362261&task=league.listall_syncable&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85

2012-06-26 00:28:21.913 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[FINISHED] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?lastsynced=1340362261&task=league.listall_syncable&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85

2012-06-26 **00:28:21**.914 zozo[11726:15203] sync Leagues sucessful

> Operation 1 finished but Operation 2 start getting data after 5 seconds. WHY?

2012-06-26 **00:28:26**.421 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[92 bytes] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?pagesize=10&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85&page=1&league_id=51&lastsynced=1340362314&task=match.schedule_syncable

2012-06-26 00:28:26.422 zozo[11726:18d03] ***[FINISHED] URL: http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/sandbox/zozo/smartphone.php?pagesize=10&session_id=1946a6504e90f80cb3bd21fb90b0be85&page=1&league_id=51&lastsynced=1340362314&task=match.schedule_syncable

2012-06-26 00:28:26.423 zozo[11726:15203] sync Matches sucessful

> From AFNetworking doc: "Another option would be to take advantage of the fact that AFJSONRequestOperation, like all of the request operations in AFNetworking, is a subclass of NSOperation. In combination with NSOperationQueue, you can easily have several requests running concurrently (you have the ability to setting a maximum number of operations to run concurrently to keep your network from getting bogged down)."

<== so what's the problem here? i just got 2 requests (92 bytes each) and i can't make them running like **concurrently**. any bugs here?

p/s: 
I've been tried with AFHTTPClient using sharedclient but i haven't no lucky. 
my server's fine and i haven't any issue with my Android client
Anybody got same problem? Are there any limitation with concurrent requets count?

http://pm[dot]mvdigital[dot]vn/ <== http://pm.mvdigital.vn/

Thanks.

EDIT:

> I found answer by myself, click here: http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/387